# Solution of $\left(\Gamma(x+c)/ \Gamma(x+d)\right)y^d/y^c = {\rm const}$

Tags: factorization, gamma-function

When I try to solve $F(x,y)= \Gamma(x+c)/\Gamma(x+d) y^d/y^c = {\rm const}$, 
I find that $y = p  x + q$ satisfies the above equation, whith specific $p$ and $q$ constants for the given constants $c$ and $d$. c > 0 and d > 0 and c /= d.

To see this numerically, I take the  $x, y$ for $1<x<10$, and $10 <y<1000$, draw contour plots for $F(x,y)$, when c = 4.2 and d = 1.8. The contour plots show linear function $y=px+q$. In other word, y=px+q has constant value of F(x,y).

However, I do not know how I can prove it mathematically. Could you give some suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try lagrange multipliers, differentiating and demanding $\nabla F = 0$

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be saying that for given $c$ and $d$, there are some constants $p$ and $q$ (not both $0$) such that $$\dfrac{\Gamma(x+c)}{\Gamma(x+d)} (px+q)^{d-c}$$ is constant.  That's obviously wrong (unless $d-c \in \{-1,0,1\}$), as you see by looking at the zeros and poles.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I am not sure if I understand your point correctly. Here is example: c=4.2, d=1.8, F(x,y) = 1e-5. Then when I input x = 0.05, 0.15, 0.25, ...., 0.95, I got y = 299.279, 311.777, 324.244,...,1506.42. This corresponds p=121.762 and q=295.941 for y = p * x + q, according to regression with correlation = 0.999998

Comment: It may be a good approximation, but is certainly not an equation.

Comment: In your example, $$\left( \dfrac{\Gamma(x+4.2)}{\Gamma(x+1.8)}\right)^{1/(4.2-1.8)} \sim  x +\frac{ 5}{2} - \dfrac{119}{600 x} + \ldots\ \text{as}\ x \to \infty$$

Comment: In general, according to Maple, $$\left( \dfrac{\Gamma(x+c)}{\Gamma(x+d)}\right)^{1/(c-d)} = x + \dfrac{c+d-1}{2} + \dfrac{1 - (c-d)^2}{24 x} + O(x^{-2})$$ as $x \to \infty$.

Answer (score 0):

If we suppose an asymptotic equation
$$
\frac{\Gamma(x+c)}{\Gamma(x+d)} \sim (px+q)^{c-d}
\qquad\text{as }x \to \infty
$$
then we get
$$
p = 1,\qquad q = \frac{c+d-1}{2}
$$
from the first two terms.  I see Robert has already noted this.